# Fixed header with relative size

Tags: html, css

I've 3 columns, heach column contain a header, and a list of items under it.
The header display a title on the left, and numbers on the right (number of items in the current column / total number of items).
The header needs to be fixed (so when I scroll, it won't move, and items will pass under it)...
but it also needs a width relative to the proportion of items in other numbers.
(If everything is in column 1, header 1 will be 100%, others 0%. If there's 1 in column 1, 3 in column 2, and 6 in column 3, header 1 will be 10%, 2 will be 30% and 3 will be 60%).
The percentage in "width: 50%" needs to be relative to the column size, problem is, if I say header is fixed, the width become relative to the page, and the proportional width doesn't works anymore.

```
<div class="content container-fluid">
<div class="row">                                       
    <div class="c1 col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
        <div class="columnHeader"><p>Column 1</p></div>
        <div class="itemsNb"><span class="nb"></span><span class="total"></span></div>
        <div class="itemsList">
            <div class="item"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="c2 col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
        <div class="columnHeader"><p>Column 2</p></div>
        <div class="itemsNb"><span class="nb"></span><span class="total"></span></div>
        <div class="itemsList">
            <div class="item"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="c3 col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
        <div class="columnHeader"><p>Column 3</p></div>
        <div class="itemsNb"><span class="nb"></span><span class="total"></span></div>
        <div class="itemsList">
            <div class="item"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.content {
    padding: 30px!important;
    overflow: auto!important;
    background: #E2E4E3;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 270px;
    right: 0;
}

.columnHeader > p {
    position: absolute;
}

.columnHeader {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.ofNumber {
    position: absolute;
    right: 25px;
    top: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333;
    background: #e2e4e3cc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 3px 5px;
}
```

So far, I've tried putting the fixed div inside the actual header div and setting it's width to inherit, but it doesn't works, width gets the same percentage I want, but is still relative to the page and not the column.

Is there a way of making a fixed element width relative to another element instead of the whole page ?
If anyone got any idea or clues, that would be great, thanks.

edit : I also tried to first display the header as relative, get it's width in pixels with js, and then change its position to fixed and apply the pixel size to it, but it only works when doing it in the console, when I do it in my code, it takes the same size as if it was width:100% and position fixed

Comment: can you make a live demo?

Comment: Can u plz send the entire code?

Comment: I tried to make a fiddle but it's complicated since I'm using bootstrap grid

Comment: @Nes Please use codepen.io, there you can easily import using cdn (in settings).